# Change soundcard sample rate from command prompt (or macro)

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I have a situation where I often need to change the sample rate of my sound card. I need to be able to do this quickly. Now I have to go in to the soundcard settings and then the Advanced tab and switch.

My first idea was to write a C# or C++ program to do this, but I want to see if there are any simpler way to do this.

Is is possible to do this via the command prompt (and then put it in a bat-file)? 
Or could I map a macro to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the steps you have to perform are always the same<sup>*</sup> and you **don't** find any other more elegant solution, you could automate the clicking/typing tasks with AutoHotkey: http://www.autohotkey.com/

---

<sup>*</sup> Dynamic content like InputBoxes for the SampleRate are easily possible.